# How can I get id of span and make it display none which is dynamically generated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, tags

I have created span tags dynamically and appended to div. Now I want to get its id, the one I select and delete it. It is something like jquery tagit. Below I am using this but it is not working. See the id can get when I click a particular span.

```
$('span').on('click', function (e){
alert(e.target.Id);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an `id` (and the `span` may well not have one), you already have a reference to the element: `this`. That's standard jQuery behavior. (In fact, it's standard across the various ways you can hook up events without jQuery too.)

So

```
$('span').on('click', function() {
    $(this).remove(); // Removes the one that was clicked
});
```

(Or, yes, add the `e` back and use `e.target`: `$(e.target).remove();`)

---

Re your comment:

> I tried using that code by giving alert also but the click event is not firing.

That suggests that the `span`s in question don't exist as of when your code runs, and so you don't end up hooking their `click` event.

To deal with that, you probably want to do a delegated handler: In dev tools, right-click one of these spans and find a common ancestor that they have that **does** exist as of when your code runs. (In the worst case, that could be `document`, but usually it's better to scope things more tightly.) Then:

```
$('selector-for-that-ancestor-element').on('click', 'span', function() {
    $(this).remove(); // Removes the one that was clicked
});
```

See [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) for details. Also, if the `span`s have any identifying characteristics (like a `class` or some attribute), you might want to include that in the delegation selector above to be more specific.

Comment: I tried using that code by giving alert also but the click event is not firing.

Comment: @Vicky: Well, that would be a *different* problem. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Vicky: Well, event delegation works regardless of who created them.

Comment: I used this and it is working. Thank You... $(document).on('click','.delete_button',function(){
    // code here
});